# Upgrading Java 7 to Java 8 - Is Java 8 String switch deprecated?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, upgrade, java-8

I have been having issues looking this up on the internet but I just upgraded my java from 1.7 to 1.8 and now I am seeing that the diamond operator is not supported anymore.

I am ok with this, but String switch statements also seem to be removed. This confuses me because the oracle documentation says this is still supported.

Am I possibly using the wrong java version in Intellije?

here is my POM maven compiler config:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And my Java Compiler settings is set to 1.8 as well (module uses JDK default).

Was this in fact deprecated? Or am I just doing something wrong?

which java command returns java 8.

maven version also returns java 8.

this isn't working anymore (in case its not clear):

```
 switch("some string"){
     case "some string":
           //some code
          break;
     default:
         //some code
  }
```

[image: Java Compiler Setting in Intellije]

Comment: Looks more like a problem in your ide. Which version of Idea are you using?

Comment: Do you have Java 8 installed?

Comment: @Luiggi Intellije 12.1.7 Ultimate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes - it is installed

Comment: What's your maven compiler plugin version?

Comment: @MGorgon Just updated Description - is 3.0

Comment: Please double check if IntelliJ is actually using your installed JDK 1.8

Comment: @Puce I added a screen shot of my Java Compiler tab

Comment: The relevant settings are not in the dialog shown, but in the "Project Structure" dialog.  Check "Project SDK" and "Project language level" under the Project Settings -> Project, and also verify that the Language Level is not overridden at the module level.

Comment: Thank you Mike! You were correct - I was using the wrong version of java in that tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone! The issue was with Intellij, not Java 8. I just had to update my Project Settings. Here is a screen shot of the page.

[image: All set now]